# How to configure ViewFlow, many functionality

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow, viewflow

How to configure ViewFlow on Django project?

I am new to Django community and I'm trying to install and test the functionality that have `ViewFlow` in Django

I've see the demo online but I would like to install it in my computer and test all the functionality and play with the code.

Specifically, I'd like know:

- how to create and configure a new form
- how to create a new flow, and assign a user specific, (because in demo, just assign a My User)
- I've see in documentation a user interface graph to model flow but in demo I can't see any.

link demo: http://demo.viewflow.io/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you somehow been confused. Viewflow is the code-based workflow library, instead of clunky UI, you can construct workflow directly in code. So, it opens a way to unlimited customization and things that are common in the standard development practice like code review, code versioning, unit-testing and etc.

The best way to start with viewflow is to follow [Quick Start](http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_quickstart.html) tutorial.

Viewflow is the library for the Django Web Framework, so the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) could also be helpful.

To create a new form - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/

To auto-assign, a user you need to provide a callable that would return a user instance on task activation.

```
mytask = flow.View(
       UpdateProcessView,
       fields=['first_field', 'second_field']
   ).Assign(
        lambda activation: .. return a user here ...
   ).Next(this.next_task)
```

Viewflow PRO version could provide a flow visualization - http://demo.viewflow.io/workflow/shipment/shipment/chart.svg/